# [SQL Server]Question on UPDATE and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have two tables, where, for a row in LEFT table I have two matching rows in RIGHT.
I am trying to update rows in LEFT table with data from RIGHT by INNER joining them.

**I would like to know, since there are  two matching rows in RIGHT, will there be two updates in LEFT or just one ?**  I am expecting two (because SELECT would get me two rows) but based on results I saw, I think only one update is happening, would like to know for sure with some explanation.

Please take a look at below sample. After executing this,I end up getting [1, C] in #LEFT. I was expecting [1, B], thinking there will two updates, first will give me [1, C] and second [1, B].

Thank you very much!

```
CREATE TABLE #LEFT
(ID INT, STS_IND CHAR NULL )

INSERT INTO #LEFT VALUES ( 1, 'A')


CREATE TABLE #RIGHT
(ID INT, STS_IND CHAR NULL )

INSERT INTO #RIGHT VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT INTO #RIGHT VALUES (1, 'B')

UPDATE
     L
SET
     L.STS_IND = R.STS_IND
FROM 
     #LEFT L
     INNER JOIN #RIGHT R
     ON L.ID = R.ID
```

Comment: The results are undefined according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql). You could end up with either C or B depending on which way the wind is blowing.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman. Could you please also clarify how many time row in #LEFT will be updated ? If it is twice then i came make few simple adjustments and get the desired result in the real scenario i have. But if it is one then i might have to change the implementation all together.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many times `#LEFT` is updated; what matters is the end result after the update. The only "adjustment" you can make to get deterministic results is to ensure only one row from `#RIGHT` matches the correlated join criteria. For example: `UPDATE L SET L.STS_IND = R.STS_IND FROM #LEFT L INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, MIN(STS_IND) AS STS_IND FROM #RIGHT GROUP BY ID) AS R ON L.ID = R.ID;`

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your question, there will be only one update. You can check that by using `@@rowcount` after update like below:

```
UPDATE
     L
SET
     L.STS_IND = R.STS_IND
FROM 
     #LEFT L
     INNER JOIN #RIGHT R
     ON L.ID = R.ID
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT Rows_Updated
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see the number of updates is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #LEFT
(   ID INT, 
    STS_IND CHAR NULL,
    COUNTER INT
)

INSERT INTO #LEFT VALUES ( 1, 'A', 0)


CREATE TABLE #RIGHT
(ID INT, STS_IND CHAR NULL )

INSERT INTO #RIGHT VALUES (1, 'C')
INSERT INTO #RIGHT VALUES (1, 'B')

UPDATE
     L
SET
     L.STS_IND = R.STS_IND,
     L.COUNTER = L.COUNTER + 1
FROM 
     #LEFT L
     INNER JOIN #RIGHT R
     ON L.ID = R.ID

SELECT *
FROM #LEFT
```